# FileHelpers Error and RecordString

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, filehelpers

I am having a curious problem with FileHelpers.  When parsing a csv file, if I have set the IgnoreFirstLines parameter of the engine to anything >0, and the first error that is encountered is on the first non-ignored line of the CSV file, the engine does not save the RecordString correctly.  It saves the first line of the csv file (an ignored line).

Example:
Engine Setup:

```
    engine.Options.IgnoreFirstLines = 2;
```

CSV file:

```
    CSV Header,,,
    Route,Comments,Route Type,Percent
    1911,Comment1,RSR,1.3%
```

If there is an error parsing the line that begins with "1911," the engine.ErrorManager.Errors[0] will incorrectly store the first line of the CSV file in the RecordString property.  The LineNumber property remains correct.  Subsequent errors will have the correct RecordString value.

I can't seem to find anything about this; I'm wondering if anyone has seen such a thing.

Comment: also asked on the FileHelpers support forums. http://www.filehelpers.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1728&p=3306#p3306

Comment: can you include the stack trace, the code, etc?  It kind of sounds like your delimiter might be wrong on your class, but it's hard to tell without the class, reading code, error stack, etc.

Comment: there is no exception/error stack in my code.  i don't think the delimiter is wrong because i can successfully parse thousands of records.  it's just this specific case where IgnoreFirstLines is set and there's an error on the first line (after the ignored lines).

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful to set the ErrorMode to SaveAndContinue and see if it fails on all records or not.

Comment: Hi, James.  It has been set to SaveAndContinue, and the rest of the csv file parses correctly.  I think it is a bug in the FileHelpers library.

Comment: Can you provide either a repro or the original code+file?  I'm happy to debug it and submit a patch